# What does it do? for i=1,select('#',...)

Tags: lua

I encountered the following code in a project that I'm working with. i don't understand the iteration part of for-loop. What is the select() function?

```
function _log (str,...)
  local LOG="/tmp/log.web"
  for i=1,select('#',...) do
    str= str.."\t"..tostring( select(i,...) )
  end
os.execute("echo \"".. str .."\" \>\> " .. LOG )
end
```

Comment: BTW, the loop can be replaced by `str=table.concat({str,...},"\t")`.

Comment: I would suggest using `file:write()` here instead of concatenating the string and then calling `os.execute()` — would be much faster. You may want to `flush` the file on the end of the line.

Comment: thanks for the optimization hints

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [Lua manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-select):

> If `index` is a number, returns all arguments after argument number index.  Otherwise, index must be the string `"#"`, and select returns the total number of extra arguments it received.

From this post on [Lua's multiple arguments and the "select" function](https://web.archive.org/web/20190912230851/https://www.emmanueloga.com/2010/12/09/lua-select.html), you can convert into a table if you really need to:

```lua
function multiple_args(...)
  local arguments = {...}  -- pack the arguments in a table
  -- do something --
  return unpack(arguments) -- return multiple arguments from a table (unpack)
end
```

Finally, if you pass "#" as index, the function returns a count of the multiple arguments provided:

```
print(select("#")) --> 0
print(select("#", {1, 2, 3})) --> 1 (single table as argument)
print(select("#", 1, 2, 3)) --> 3
print(select("#", {1,2,3}, 4, 5, {6,7,8}) --> 4 (a table, 2 numbers, another table)
```